# How to make cypress wait for the end of a vuex action before to clean localStorage?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, cypress

I use `cypress` to test an app made with `vuejs` / `vuex` / `graphql`. It works thanks to [this great article](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/).

One test dispatches a `vuex` action from a component. This action makes multiple requests to the server. In every request, an auth token is injected from `localStorage` (if it exists) to the `headers`.

**The problem**: the first request of the action works fine but subsequent requests do not have the auth token in the headers anymore and fail. From what I understand, Cypress does not wait for all the requests to complete before cleaning `localStorage`.

**component**

```js
<template>
  <button @click="save">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    save() {
      this.$store.dispatch('update')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**store**

```js
export const actions = {
  async update({ commit, dispatch }) {
    try {
      // the token is here
      console.log('a. token ->', localStorage.getItem('token'))

      // this works
      const res = await apiUpdate()

      // now the token is null, but why? Is it because of Cypress?
      console.log('b. token ->', localStorage.getItem('token'))

      commit('set', res)

      // this fails because the token is null in localStorage
      await apiAnotherUpdate()

    } catch (e) {
      //…
    }
  })
```

**test**

```js
describe("My app", () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080/");

    // log the user and sets the token
    cy.login();
  });

  it("test button", function() {
    cy.get("button").click();
    cy.get("#page").should("contain", "Updated content");
  });
});
```

**What is the proper way to make this test work?**

Thank you

---

**edit**

I found an *ugly* fix using `cy.wait(2000)` at the end of the test, but am still open to a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the function `async` in the component solved it.

```js
methods: {
  async save() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('update')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

As an extra, you could also use the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-localstorage-commands) plugin to persist localStorage between tests, so you'll be able to do login only once:

In support/commands.js:

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";
```

In your tests:

```js
before(() => {
  // Do your login stuff here
  cy.saveLocalStorage();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.restoreLocalStorage();
});
```